# Using Nginx as proxy to avoid CORS

Tags: angularjs, rest, nginx, cors

I have this:

[image]

Now I want to use the nginx server I have there to serve all my static files and to proxy all requests to api.stuff.com. Is this possible? Is nginx the best tool to do this? What would the configuration be?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can do that. With nginx you need to set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header and set the value to your api.stuff.com. To add the headers you need http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule

Comment: http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/

Answer (score 3):

One way is to tell nginx to actually proxy the calls to the api, so for example if you want to call `api.domain.com/users` you'll instead call `example.com/users` and nginx will proxy the `/users` call to the api since it's not present locally, of course this method is harder to maintain because you'll need to do the mapping your self.

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  root /path/to/root;
  location / {
    try_files $uri @proxy_to_api;
  }
  location @proxy_to_api {
    # add whatever proxy settings you want
    proxy_pass http://api.domain.com;
  }
}
```

The other way would be telling nginx to tell your client that it's ok to do calls to the api server, this way your client can access `api.domain.com` by it self without help from nginx

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "api.domain.com";
```